# Get TimeSeries data in .CSV format from ThingsBoard Dashboard through API calls

Tags: thingsboard

I am stuck in getting time-series data from ThingsBoard dashboard through an API call, I want to do the call from my Jypyter Notebook.
I have tried some experiments on the Swagger UI, the Rest API of ThingsBoard but I am still can't find a way.

Can anyone help, please?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get a valid token with your user credentials. Following is the script to get it via python jupyter

```
import requests
import json

################## SET Credentials, URL and GET TOKEN ##################


username="yourUsername"
pw="yourPassword"
tokenUrl ="yourThingsboardUrl/api/auth/login"



headers={
    "accept":"application/json",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}

params={
    "username":username,
    "password": pw
}

response = requests.post('https://' +tokenUrl ,  headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))

# SET token from response.json to token variable
token = response.json()['token']
```

After that you can attach the token variable to any REST API request like so:

```
response = requests.get("https://yourURL.com:yourPort/api/plugins/telemetry/DEVICE/"+ yourDeviceId + "/keys/timeseries", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)})
```

Here I'm requesting alle the available keys for a specific device with "yourDeviceId"

After that do something like

```
data = response.json()
json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

To work with the data that you requested in an appropriate format